Как скачать zip архив приватного репозитория по url ссылке через токен?
Я делал все по следующим шагам как указано здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/76922082/15735942:

You can use read-only access token to share a private repository.
git clone https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
To generate a new token:

Go to Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens >
Fine-grained tokens > Generate new token.

Select the repositories you want to share under Repository access >
Only select repositories.

Set the access level of the token to read-only in Permissions >
Repository permissions > Contents > Access: read-only.

Finally, click on Generate token.



Я пробовал создавать токен и использовать следующий формат ссылки: https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<username>/<repository>/archive/refs/heads/main.zip, но вместо скачивания zip файла я получаю ошибку 404: Not Found. В чём может быть проблема?

По поводу скачивания по ссылке вида
https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<username>/<repository>/archive/refs/heads/<ref>.zip

- такой вариант вполне рабочий, вот проверил через curl:

При открытии этой же ссылки в браузере предлагает скачать файл.
Проверьте, что все указали правильно, в том числе имя ветки (ветка действительно main, как вы указываете, а не например master).

Другие способы скачивания:
git clone предназначено только для клонирования репозитория, а не для скачивания произвольного файла. Через него можно разве что склонировать репозиторий, потом уже упаковать в zip.
Скачать можно с помощью Github API, как тут показано: Download a repository archive (zip)
Например, через curl:
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/zipball/REF \
  --output file.zip

или утилиту gh (Github CLI):
gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/zipball/REF > file.zip


OWNER - владелец репозитория
REPO - имя репозитория
REF - ветка (например, main или master), тэг или хэш коммита

При использовании утилиты gh предварительно нужно будет авторизоваться командой gh auth login.
Например, так (токен будет взят из файла mytoken.txt):
gh auth login --with-token < mytoken.txt

Для утилиты gh кроме прав на чтение репозиторев нужно будет еще право read:org, для запроса через curl (или просто http запросов) это не обязательно.

Спасибо за ответ. То есть не получиться сделать также, как указано здесь https://defold.com/manuals/libraries/#basic-access-authentication? К сожалению, я не могу использовать curl или gh, так как скачивание архива происходит на стороне игрового движка

¿В качестве YOUR-TOKEN здесь случаем не должен использоваться другой токен, для доступа к API, отличный от PAT?

@user7860670, я через обычный классический токен работаю с graphql github api. В доках правда указано, что fine-grained вроде как нужен: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#download-a-repository-archive-zip--fine-grained-access-tokens

@user7860670 скачивает с обычным классическим PAT, zip целый: https://i.sstatic.net/wFecM.png

@Haslin я проверил, у меня такой вариант работает. Проверьте что правильно все указали, например ветка точно main а не master.

@insolor, проверил ветку, указана правильно, но всё равно не работает

@Haslin проверьте все: имя пользователя, токен, имя репозитория, ветку. Плюс проверьте что у пользователя вообще есть доступ к этому репозиторию. И еще при создании токена должно быть добавлено право на чтение репозиториев.
